# Controlling visibility of custom actions depending on views

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, custom-actions

I am building a Sharepoint Online site which is heavily dependent on workflows. I am using custom actions for workflows which are to be manually started by the user on demand. In some cases, custom actions are showing in views where they don't make sense to actually show.

Consider this scenario:

I have a document library called: Orders.

The hierarchy looks something like this:

Document Library: Orders
Document Sets: SingleOrderStage1, SingleOrderStage2, etc etc
Documents: SubOrderStage1, SubOrderStage2

I have a custom action called: ApproveOrder which is meant to run on the Document set types. Then, I have another custom action called: ApproveSubOrder, which is meant to run on the Document types.

I want the custom action ApproveOrder to show in the document library view, where all the document sets, corresponding to all the stages are showing. On the other hand, I want the custom action ApproveSubOrder to only show in the document set view, where all the documents are showing inside the document sets.

This may be a small detail, but the difference that it makes to the user interface and to the user experience is huge.

I am inexperienced in Sharepoint and I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.